# It's regarding AngularJS $data

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

In our code below line is mentioned:
< tr ng-repeat="usrChanges in $data" >
I am using angularJS (angular1), I am unable to find the $data in Controller.
I want to do some operations on it before displaying on webpage.
Help me in storing data of "$data" in any other variable in controller.

Comment: From what I know $data will be inside a directive/component in controller behind `$scope` or `scope`

Comment: It would be great if you can share some code snippet from your controller so that others can get a better insight of problem and help.

Answer (score 0):

`$data` should be attached to your $scope inside the controller or directive bveing used at the page. Try finding where you are assigning `$scope.$data`.